# Azure functions upload file broken?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureportal

When I upload function files via the portal, all files get this prefix

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2prVJaVBFIetixZM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="index.js"
Content-Type: text/javascript
```

and this suffix

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2prVJaVBFIetixZM--
```

this used to work a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmin,

The portal has been recently updated and it looks like this is a regression.

We've openeed [this issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/909) and will address the problem ASAP.

Thank you for reporting this!

Comment: I also opened another issue as I didn't see your reply here. https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/910