# Metadata file could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In azure functions I uploaded private dll's to bin folder using following instructions

If you need to reference a private assembly, you can upload the assembly file into a bin folder relative to your function and reference it by using the file name (e.g. #r "MyAssembly.dll").

but I when run the function, I am getting this error for every dll. "Metadata file could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata"

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're adding references to native binaries as well. Your references must be .NET assemblies. If you're deploying native indirect dependencies, you don't need to reference those from your function script.

**UPDATE:** There as a defect in the last portal deployment causing the content of files uploaded in the portal to be prefixed and suffixed with multipart form data, invalidating files.

The issue has been fixed and is being rolled out, but in the meantime, please upload the files using Kudu to workaround this issue. You can find more information about the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137093/azure-functions-upload-file-broken) (and by following the issue link)

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the OP. My assembly is targeted to .Net 4.6. Do you have any other ideas what this might cause?

Comment: Marc, can you share some more details about how you're referencing the assembly, how you're deploying it, etc? Is this something you can easily repro with code you can share? If so, could you setup a repo on GitHub so we can take a look at it?

Comment: Deleting and Recreating the function fixed this error but i am still experiencing another error. @FabioCavalcante when you get a chance, could you look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212166/constructor-on-type-xxx-not-found

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was what I described above (having explicit references to the unmanaged DLLs) what you originally had? This cases of binding failures leading to a bad state after correction should be addressed in the next release of the runtime.

I've added a comment to your other question.

Comment: @Marc added an update to the answer, hopefully that provides you more information about what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue while building MAUI app in android platform. A native module was present in the project with .so extension. But a windows native DLL also present in the project for the purpose for running the same project in windows. Excluding the windows native DLL while building running in android fixed the issue. Sometimes I have to close the project and delete bin and obj folder and then rebuild the project to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this issue in .Net when I add mysql 8.0.32

the error was "Metadata file  krb5_64.dll' could not be opened -- PE image doesn't contain managed metadata"

so the solution was to update nuget package of Mysql to version 8.0.32.1
so the error gone